# Warning: mysqli_stmt::close() [mysqli-stmt.close]: invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt... why?

Tags: php, prepared-statement

for learning purposes, why does php cries about the following code and gives the following warning:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::close() [mysqli-stmt.close]: invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt in C:\public_html\admin\disctrack.php on line 14


12    $conn = connect('w'); // connect to a database in write mode
13    $stmt = $conn->stmt_init(); // initialize a prepared statement
14    $stmt->close(); // close statement
```

Comment: It probably means there was an error in your connect() function. Try wrapping everything in try-catch blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [mysqli::stmt_init documentation](http://ch2.php.net/mysqli_stmt_init):

> Any subsequent calls to any mysqli_stmt function will fail until mysqli_stmt_prepare() was called.

Comment: bingo!... i've tested it and when added a prepare statement, it stops crying.... still, it should be able to close without any warnings... just saying