# mysqli_stmt::execute(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt getting error when connect three databases

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting mysqli_stmt::execute(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt error for database3 when I am trying connect with three databases,Here is my code

```
global $db;
$stmt = $db->stmt_init();

global $db2;
$stmt2 = $db2->stmt_init();

global $db3;
$stmt3 = $db3->stmt_init();


/*****************Database3************/

/*** Icube ***/

$stmt->prepare( "SELECT n.offer_id, n.name, n.net_provider ,s.description,p.payout,q.categories FROM affilate_offer_findall_icube n 
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN affiliate_offe_findbyid_icube s ON s.offer_id = n.offer_id 
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN affiliate_offer_getpayoutdetails_icube p ON p.offer_id = s.offer_id 
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN affiliate_offer_get_categories_icube q ON q.offer_id = p.offer_id  WHERE
                n.visible='1'
        ");

$stmt->execute();
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); // <--------- currently missing!!!
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt); 
$rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
$stmt->bind_result($offer_id, $name, $net_provider, $description, $payout, $categories);
$storeid = 0;
while($info = $stmt->fetch()) 
{
     $storeid+=1;
     $values3_icube[] = '("'.$storeid.'", "'.$offer_id.'", "'.$name.'", "'.$net_provider.'", "'.$description.'", "'.$notes.'", "'.$payout.'", "'.$categories.'")';

}

$stmt3->prepare("REPLACE INTO main_vendor_db(store_id, offer_id, name, net_provider, description, cashback, categories) VALUES".implode(',', $values3_icube));
$stmt3->execute();
```

**I am getting error here **

```
 $stmt3->prepare("REPLACE INTO main_vendor_db(store_id,offer_id, name,net_provider,description,cashback,categories) VALUES".implode(',', $values3_icube));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so much inconsistency in your code, that it's no wonder it fails somewhere.

- First of all, you aren't actually using prepared statements, sending raw SQL instead. So, all the hassle in vain.
- Second, all these things like `/ <--------- currently missing!!!` remarks makes it positively impossible to answer. How do we expected to regard this comment?
- Third, `mysqli_stmt::execute():` clearly says that error occurred with execute, while you are indicating the line with prepare. And, judging by the error message, `mysqli_stmt::execute()` in question is likely about that commented line from above
- Fourth, this is apparently incomplete code and incomplete error message.
- Fifth, you are implementing auto_increment mysql's feature by hand.
- Sixth, three databases, taken with all the above, seems *very* peculiar.

Let me advise you to ask a completely different question, regarding the *task* you are trying to solve and get the *proper* way to do so.

Answer (score -1):

According to [mysqli_stmt::execute documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

**Any subsequent calls to any mysqli_stmt function will fail until mysqli_stmt_prepare() was called.**

Also check-

[Problem with multiple prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039151/problem-with-multiple-prepared-statements)

[Warning: mysqli_stmt::close() [mysqli-stmt.close]: invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt... why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297640/warning-mysqli-stmtclose-mysqli-stmt-close-invalid-object-or-resource-my)

Comment: what I have to do in my coding?

Comment: Note that you shouldn't need to call `mysqli->stmt_init()`, which is present (as `mysqli_stmt_init`) to support procedural programming. Instead, you can use `mysqli->prepare()`.

Comment: try closing previous statement using `$stmt1->close();` before executing next statement.